# Access to equal class from a different source

Tags: java

Imagine having two identical classes from a different external source (.jar). Those two classes share nothing in common ie don't extend or implement same base class/interface. They do the same work or very similar but since they share nothing in common so one can not use generics very effectively. One ends up with a lot of duplicated code when using those two classes.

Is there any elegant way to avoid that without involving reflection?

Update:
Classes have same name and same methods with same arguments from a different package.

Example:

```
import com.v1.BuilderFactory;
import com.v1.Foo;

class Builder1 {
    private final BuilderFactory builderFactory;

    Builder1(BuilderFactory builderFactory) {
        this.builderFactory = builderFactory;
    }
    Foo doStuff(Request request) {

        builderFactory.doStuff();
        return builderFactory.build();
    }
}
```

… and …

```
import com.v2.BuilderFactory;
import com.v2.Foo;

class Builder2 {
    private final BuilderFactory builderFactory;

    Builder2(BuilderFactory builderFactory) {
        this.builderFactory = builderFactory;
    }
    Foo doStuff(Request request) {

        builderFactory.doStuff();
        return builderFactory.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail, e.g. what do you mean by "identical"? Same name? Same package? How do you want to use those two classes? How is that different from using two totally unrelated classes?

Comment: i think you can have these classes instance as some wrapper class/interface member and expose properities. so they can be indirectly implement base/interface.

Comment: Maybe you can write a wrapper class that does the work with a  common interface, and depending on instantation values or a parameter it does it one way or the other...

Comment: @LeiYang not sure I understand. How would you achieve that?

Comment: @Turo that would again mean code duplication. Maybe a code sample as a demonstration from my side would help?

Comment: @krizajb i mean, maybe you're looking for some built in language grammer, but this looks more like a design pattern use case. so just find a suitable pattern in the design pattern books.

Comment: You probably need the Adapter design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Whoops.

When I first wrote this, I failed to notice that the `Foo` objects being returned by the method were of two different types from two different packages.

This means the original problem statement involves entirely separate code, different types, apples and oranges. No point in trying to join these disparate types.

I’ll leave the code in place below as it may be of interest to some in a similar situation. But this code does *not* properly solve the Question’s problem.  If there were only a single type of `Foo`, then this code would have solved the problem.

---

As noted in your Question, your scenario precludes using the type system of Java directly. This means you cannot use polymorphism to dispatch automatically to the appropriate factory’s method. So we need to manually dispatch.

You will need to write redundant code that addresses each of the two separate types. However, you can wrap that code into a single new class. That new class contains an instance of either one type or the other. The benefit is that all the calling code can remain blissfully ignorant of the fact that there are alternative types implementing the functionality. The calling code gets an object of the wrapper, and the wrapper internally dispatches to one type or the other.

Define a wrapper class that contains an instance of either.

```java
class BuilderWrapped
{
    // Only *one* of these two member fields will ever be populated. The other remains `null`. 
    private final com.v1.BuilderFactory builderFactory1;
    private final com.v2.BuilderFactory builderFactory2;

    // Constructors
    // We have a pair of constructors, one for each of the two types that we wrap.

    BuilderWrapped( com.v1.BuilderFactory f ) 
    {
        this.builderFactory1 = Objects.requireNonNull( f ) ;
    }

    BuilderWrapped( com.v2.BuilderFactory f ) 
    {
        this.builderFactory2 = Objects.requireNonNull( f ) ;
    }

    // Logic
    Foo doStuff( Request request ) {
        if ( Objects.nonNull( this.builderFactory1 ) { … use that factory to return a `Foo` object … }
        else if ( Objects.nonNull( this.builderFactory2 ) { … use that factory to return a `Foo` object … }
        else { … throw exception because this case should be impossible (defensive programming) … }
    }

}
```

Usage starts with instantiating our `BuilderWrapped` code.

```
BuilderWrapped bw = new BuilderWrapped( new com.v2.BuilderFactory() ) ;
```

Pass `bw` to some calling code which can then call the `Foo doStuff( Request request )` method which in turn calls upon the logic implemented in our contained `com.v2.BuilderFactory` object’s `Foo doStuff( Request request )` method.

```
Foo foo = bw.doStuff( someRequest ) ;
```

Comment: Please notice how Foo is also coming from a different package.

Comment: @krizajb Nope, i did not notice that. Than you have entirely separate code, apples and oranges. No point in trying to join these disparate types.

Comment: Foo is again same class from a different package. But I don't think that changes anything.

Comment: @krizajb No, *not* the same class. You cannot have one class in two packages. Sharing the same name is a coincidence, that does not make them one class. For example, `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date` share the same class name “Date” but they are two different classes. The entire premise of your Question is faulty, being based on the coincidence of some class names.

Comment: The difference between those two being completly different, while mine are identical. Imagine having SDK from version 1.11 and 1.12, but you are trying to integrate both SDKs. You end up with 99% of the same code when using those two SDKs. Hope I made it a little bit understandable.

Comment: @krizajb **Different packages means different classes.** No getting around that. If you had access to the source code, you could define an interface implemented by classes in both packages. But your Question said you had only executables (JARs), not source code. So in your scenario, the two different sets of classes share nothing in common technically, totally different types regardless of how similar they may seem to you.

Comment: I understand, hence the question. Thank you very much for helping out.